# Threading Slower than synchronous File I/O

Tags: python, io

My knowledge of threading is that in python its best reserved for tasks where I/O is the bottleneck of your application. My understanding is that would cover file reading/writing to disk given that the script is writing to file. However, when I've tested this I either get faster results (or just as fast) with a synchronous loop as I do using threads to write to disk as seen in the code below:

```
def write_file(response_data: dict) -> None:
    try:
        file_path = Path('/', f"{response_data['id']}.json"
        with file_path.open("w") as file:
            json.dump(response_data, file)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Unable to write file")
        log.error("".join(traceback.TracebackException.from_exception(e).format()))

log.info("Time start threads")
start = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(write_file, final_responses)
log.info("Time end threads")
end = time.time()
log.info("Total time for threads %s", (end - start) / 60)

log.info("Time start no threads")
start = time.time()
for response in final_responses:
    write_file(response)
log.info("Time end no threads")
end = time.time()
log.info("Total time for no threads %s", (end - start) / 60)
```

`final_responses` is just a list of `dict` that I want to write to individual files. Ive ran this several times with varying list sizes but the results are similar for both the threaded and synchronous versions. I'm not sure exactly what I'm not understanding here, is the `GIL` forcing me to be synchronous anyways? Is my OS only able to write one file at a time?

Comment: The bandwidth for accessing a disk is restricted and especially for mechanical disks the switching between files needs additional time. At most one thread should be designated for accessing a local disk.

Comment: Writing JSON is still mostly CPU limited for formatting the file. Multithreaded IO works for large binary files like images, not small text files.

Comment: @MichaelButscher In my experience that is outdated advise. Multiple threads often lead to better I/O performance, especially when writing multiple files and/or on SSDs. Case in point: Overlapped I/O in Windows uses a threadpool. robocopy uses threads, too